# Does the 3SAT problems have to have consistent operators?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, boolean-algebra

What are the rules pertaining to 3SAT as to the actual boolean equation?

The main thing I do not understand is in a given boolean expression within a single clause can you have both AND + OR operators i.e. (x1 **&** x2 **|** x3) or do they have to remain consistent i.e. (x1 **&** x2 **&** x3) or (x1 **|** x2 **|** x3)?

That being said when connecting clauses together do the boolean operators have to be consistent?

i.e. (x1 & x2 & x3) **&** (x1 & x2 & x3) **&** (x1 & x2 & x3)

```
or
```

i.e. (x1 & x2 & x3) **|** (x1 & x2 & x3) **|** (x1 & x2 & x3)

or can they be mixed up like

i.e. (x1 & x2 & x3) **|** (x1 & x2 & x3) **&** (x1 & x2 & x3)

```
or
```

i.e. (x1 & x2 & x3) **&** (x1 & x2 & x3) **|** (x1 & x2 & x3)

Can a 3SAT problem just be a huge jumble of different logic operators or do they have to remain consistent throughout the equation? Ever example I have seen has consistent operators and I cant seem to find the answer to the question anywhere.

Comment: 3SAT is given in 3-CNF form, look what it does mean. Curcuit SAT has no such restrictions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56369/14578

Comment: @rus9384 Write an answer?

Answer (score 1):

3SAT is a problem of deciding satisfiability of boolean formula in 3CNF form: this means that

1. Each clause has either exactly 3 different literals in each clause or at most 3 literals in each clause, according to different definitions.
2. Only $\lor$ operators can be used inside clauses (not counting varible negations).
3. Only $\land$ operators can be used outside clauses.

[General] SAT problem does not have a limit on number of literals in a clause and Circuit SAT allows any boolean formula.